How to invoke Agent using Bedrock Agent Runtime Client in AWS SDK with PHP
How to properly parse the result from invokeAgent.
`$client = new BedrockAgentRuntimeClient([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
    'credentials' => [
        'key' => '...',
        'secret' => '...',
    ],
]);

$payloadAgent = [
    'agentId' => '...',
    'agentAliasId' => '...',
    'sessionId' => '123456',
    'enableTrace' => false,
    'inputText' => 'prompt to send to the agent',
];

$completion = '';
try {
    $response = $client->invokeAgent($payloadAgent);
    print_r($response);

    foreach ($response['completion'] as $chunkEvent) {
        $chunk = $chunkEvent['chunk'];
        $decodedResponse = utf8_decode($chunk['bytes']);
        $completion .= $decodedResponse;
    }
    
} catch (AwsException|Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}`

Output is:
Failed to parse unknown message type. in /vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Api/Parser/EventParsingIterator.php:74
How to fetch the output as how it is displayed in case of using AWS Console and testing the agent there?

I've implemented this code with Bedrock Agent Runtime Client in AWS SDK.
$credentials = new Aws\Credentials\Credentials(KEY, SECRET);

$client = new BedrockAgentRuntimeClient([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
    'credentials' => $credentials
]);

$payloadAgent = [
    'agentId' => '...',
    'agentAliasId' => '...',
    'sessionId' => '...',
    'enableTrace' => true,
    'inputText' => 'prompt to send to the agent',
];

$completion = '';
try {
    $response = $client->invokeAgent($payloadAgent);
    foreach ($response['completion'] as $chunkEvent) {
        if (isset($chunkEvent['chunk'])) {
            $chunk = $chunkEvent['chunk'];
            $decodedResponse = utf8_decode($chunk['bytes']);
            $completion .= $decodedResponse;
        }
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getCode().' - '.$e->getMessage();
}

return $completion;

Check the docs for references. 1, 2, 3 and the official example code.
Have a nice one!

This SDK component doesn't handle errors properly. It supports :message-type values event and error, but in my case the incoming message type was exception, and it came with an :exception-type header containing  validationException, and a payload of:
{"message":"Failed to retrieve resource because it doesn't exist. Retry the request with a different resource identifier."}

Until Amazon fixes the PHP SDK, you will have to hack the library if you want to see the actual error that's occurring. But in case it's the same as mine above, I would double-check your Region, Agent ID, and Agent Alias ID parameters.
In particular: The agentAliasId is not the name you entered when you created the alias. Each alias has a name as well as a generated ID.
